# how i get all table with select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i got a problem when i select all table with query.

this is the code of query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user, pendidikan, cv, foto, data_pribadi 
WHERE pendidikan.id 
  and user.id 
  and cv.id 
  and foto.id 
  and data_pribadi.id = 1
```

when i use that query, i get much data not just id = 1. how i get just table from user, pendidikan, cv, foto, data_pribadi but just id = 1??

just information : id is foregn key from table : pendidikan, cv, foto, data_pribadi and id primary key from table user

Comment: First you need to learn how to do a [**JOIN**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Your query joined all tables..try to add more details here.. sample data and your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` sintaxis something like this depending on how is the relationship betwen tables.

```
SELECT u.*  --, p.*, c.*, f.*, d.*   select what fields you need
FROM user u
JOIN pendidikan p
  ON u.pendikan_id = p.pendikan_id
JOIN cv c
  ON u.cv_id = c.id
JOIN foto f
  ON u.foto_id = f.foto_id
JOIN data_prabgadi d
  ON u.data_prabgadi_id = d.id
WHERE d.id = 1
```